# haproxy online acl analyzer or debugger for acl analysis

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to check the haproxy why the `acl` is not matching.

May be logs or debugm as why nothing matched or can there be an online tool for the same?

Comment: Please ask about your actual problem, rather than about tools.  Create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't work as you expect, then show it to us, so that we can help you understand.  ACLs either match or they don't, and while bugs are possible, unexpected behavior is usually the result of not understanding how to correctly express the condition you are attempting to match.

Comment: actually the acl i wrote ,, were suppose to match, but they are not matching as expected, hence looking for similar tools

Comment: The most likely reason for an ACL not to match is that it is written with invalid/inconsistent logic, or used incorrectly.  Please show us the ACL and describe the problem.

Comment: was looking for something siliar to https://regex101.com for regex .. we can close this q if needed